# electron-builder autoUpdater

Tags: node.js, reactjs, electron, electron-builder

I'm using electron-builder autoUpdater in my electron application. While using the events given by electron-builder:

```
app.on("ready", function () {
  autoUpdater.checkForUpdatesAndNotify();
});

autoUpdater.on("checking-for-update", () => {
  sendStatusToWindow("Checking for update...");
});

autoUpdater.on("update-available", (info) => {
  sendStatusToWindow("Update available.");
  sendStatusToWindow("about to download");
});

autoUpdater.on("update-not-available", (info) => {
  sendStatusToWindow("Update not available.");
});

autoUpdater.on("error", (err) => {
  sendStatusToWindow("Error in auto-updater. " + err);
});

autoUpdater.on("download-progress", (progressObj) => {
  sendStatusToWindow("download-progress triggered");
  let log_message = "Download speed: " + progressObj.bytesPerSecond;
  log_message = log_message + " - Downloaded " + progressObj.percent + "%";
  log_message =
    log_message +
    " (" +
    progressObj.transferred +
    "/" +
    progressObj.total +
    ")";
  sendStatusToWindow(log_message);
});

autoUpdater.on("update-downloaded", (info) => {
  sendStatusToWindow("Update downloaded");
  autoUpdater.quitAndInstall();
});
```

The code is perfectly running, Only curious about between

```
autoUpdater.on("update-available", (info) => {});
```

and

```
autoUpdater.on("download-progress", (progressObj) => {})
```

has a very long delay,
I thought this might be coming due to internet speed but I've switch to better connection with over 50Mbps but still the download-progress took too long for almost 4 to 5 minuts to trigger and track progress.

here is my package.json dependencies for package version reference:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^14.0.1",
    "electron-builder": "^22.11.7",
    "electron-notarize": "^1.1.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "electron-log": "^4.4.1",
    "electron-updater": "^4.3.9"
  },
```